# Unable to upload txt,xls files from my upload.php

Tags: php

I have created upload.php script. I am able to upload images but I am not able to upload txt,xls or video files.

I have added the desired code in my script but still its not uploading. Below is my `upload.php` script

I have added `&& $imageFileType != "txt" && $imageFileType != "xls" )` , still it is not allowing it. Why is this?

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" && $imageFileType != "txt" && $imageFileType != "xls" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

My html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is this `$imageFileType` ?

Comment: to upload any type of file, just remove the file type check line. Though i strongly advise against doing that. Because trojans and other harmful files could also pass as valid

Comment: this is my code, its not working

Comment: i added the txt and xls extension - `&& $imageFileType != "txt" && $imageFileType != "xls" )`, still it is not allowing it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upload files in php using html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8665231/how-to-upload-files-in-php-using-html)

Comment: have you added enctype="multipart/form-data" in your html form tag? or content type in case of ajax?

Comment: Please replace your if condition to a better format like `if( !in_array($imageFileType, ['jpg','png','jpeg','gif','txt','xls']) {...}`

Comment: What is echoed by your code?

Comment: File is not an image.Sorry, your file was not uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working properly. If you get the error output is because a txt file doesn't have `height` and `width` so `getimagesize()` will return `FALSE`.

Edit your code like this:

```
<?php
    if( isset( $_POST[ "submit" ] ) ) {
        $target_dir = "upload/";
        $target_file = $target_dir . basename( $_FILES[ "fileToUpload" ][ "name" ] );
        $uploadOk = 1;
        $imageFileType = strtolower( pathinfo( $target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION ) );
        if( !in_array($imageFileType, ['jpg','png','jpeg','gif','txt','xls']) ) {
            // First check for supported file format
            echo "File format not supported.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        } else{
            if( in_array($imageFileType, ['jpg','png','jpeg','gif']) ){
                // It coult be an image
                $check = getimagesize( $_FILES[ "fileToUpload" ][ "tmp_name" ] );
                if( $check !== false ) {
                    // Yes, definitely an image
                    echo "File is an image - " . $check[ "mime" ] . ".";
                    $uploadOk = 1;
                }
                else {
                    echo "File is not an image.";
                    $uploadOk = 0;
                }
            }
            if( $uploadOk != 0 && file_exists( $target_file ) ) {
                echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
                $uploadOk = 0;
            }
            if( $uploadOk != 0 && $_FILES[ "fileToUpload" ][ "size" ] > 500000 ) {
                echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
                $uploadOk = 0;
            }
            if( $uploadOk == 0 ) {
                echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
                // if everything is ok, try to upload file
            }else {
                if( move_uploaded_file( $_FILES[ "fileToUpload" ][ "tmp_name" ], $target_file ) ) {
                    echo "The file " . basename( $_FILES[ "fileToUpload" ][ "name" ] ) . " has been uploaded.";
                }
                else {
                    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @user2828442 Where? It's working as expected on my pc

Comment: is this entire code u provided or i have to append this code in my file ?

Comment: This replaces your PHP code only. Can you tell me the entire error string you get?